# Can't get global hotkeys working in Rhythmbox 3.1

Tags: rhythmbox

To be specific, the volume knob & mute are working fine everywhere. Play, pause, next, & previous are working fine in Exaile, but not in Rhythmbox. I uninstalled Exaile after using it to test the hotkeys, just in case.

The keyboard shortcuts are set properly, as far as I can tell; they all start with XF86.

I went looking for appropriate plugins, but haven't found any; I also dug through [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817241/media-keys-dont-work?newreg=cdbad13c0d0649628fbb596df8719bb8), with no luck. & that's about as far as my clue goes. Halp pls?

I'm running Linux Mint 18.

Many thanks!

(Bringing this over from AskUbuntu because I'm running Linux Mint, not Ubuntu, & everything is better when I PAY ATTENTION.)

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04, and with Clementine too.

Comment: You should probably delete [your question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1160772/309110); we very much dislike [having the same question on multiple sites.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4073/23408 "Cross-posting Etiquette")

Comment: Scott, done, & thank you; wasn't sure if that was my responsibility or if a mod would need to do it.